# Does caching a new table with an existing table name remove old contents from memory?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Using, Spark 1.5.2:

```
dfOld.registerTempTable("oldTableName")
hiveContext.cacheTable("oldTableName") 
// ....
// do something
// ....
dfNew.registerTempTable("oldTableName")
hiveContext.cacheTable("oldTableName")
```

Now when I use the "oldTableName" table I do get the latest contents from dfNew but do the contents of dfOld get removed from the memory?

Or is the right usage to do this:

```
dfOld.registerTempTable("oldTableName")
hiveContext.cacheTable("oldTableName") 
// ....
// do something
// ....
dfNew.registerTempTable("oldTableName")
hiveContext.unCacheTable("oldTableName") <========== un-cache the old contents first
hiveContext.cacheTable("oldTableName")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO, The contents are not uncached until specifically asking the spark cacheManager to do so using `hiveContext.uncacheTable("tableName")` or `hiveContext.uncache()`[Warning: This uncaches all tables].
Proof: On experiment, the "Storage" tab clearly shows duplicate entries for the same table.
For this code segment:

```
dfOld.registerTempTable("myColorsTable")
hiveContext.cacheTable("myColorsTable") 
// ....
// do something
// ....
dfNew.registerTempTable("myColorsTable")
hiveContext.cacheTable("myColorsTable")
```

[image: Duplicate caching seen on storage tab]

On ./bin/spark-shell

```
scala> df.collect
res54: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([blue,#0033FF], [red,#FF0000], [green,#FSKA])  <=== 3 rows

scala> df2.collect
res55: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([blue,#0033FF], [red,#FF0000])  <=== 2 rows

scala> df.registerTempTable("myColorsTable")

scala> sqlContext.isCached("myColorsTable") 
res58: Boolean = false

scala> sqlContext.cacheTable("myColorsTable") <=== cache table in df(3 rows)

scala> sqlContext.isCached("myColorsTable")
res60: Boolean = true

scala> sqlContext.sql("select * from myColorsTable").foreach(println) <=== sql is running on df(3 rows)
[blue,#0033FF]
[red,#FF0000]
[green,#FSKA]

scala> df2.registerTempTable("myColorsTable") <=== register another table with the same table name

scala> sqlContext.isCached("myColorsTable")
res63: Boolean = false

scala> sqlContext.sql("select * from myColorsTable").foreach(println) <=== sql is running on df2(2 rows)
[blue,#0033FF]
[red,#FF0000]

scala> sqlContext.cacheTable("myColorsTable")
15/12/19 09:53:55 WARN CacheManager: Asked to cache already cached data. <=====
```

From [CacheManager#cacheQuery()](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0a7bca2da04aefff16f2513ec27a92e69ceb77f6/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/CacheManager.scala#L87):

```
 if (lookupCachedData(planToCache).nonEmpty) {
      logWarning("Asked to cache already cached data.")
```

Comment: I wonder what the reason is for not replacing the old table with the new one. When you go to retrieve the table named "myColorsTable" which one will you get (since they are not necessarily the same)?

Comment: Calling sqlContext.uncacheTable(name) did not seem to remove the duplicate entry from the storage tab.

Comment: Did you check isCached?

Comment: I didn't realize something could be in the storage table and not be cached.